# How to improve my academic vocabulary

Tags: writing

I'm an international student and would like to prepare myself for a PhD which I will possibly be starting in 8 months' time. I need to improve my academic vocabulary and don't know what the roadmap is for that.

Comment: What is an "academic vocabulary"?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to clarify: What kind of vocabulary are we talking about? Are you a native speaker of whatever language’s vocabulary you would like to learn?

Answer (score 8):

I am not quite sure what you mean by "academic vocabulary". If you mean words which appear in your field, read papers in your field or, if their level is too specialized, books for students.

On the other hand, if you mean words like "paper", "rejection", "withdrawal", "paywalled journal" etc., you may want to start at Academia Stack Exchange: reading many questions and answers here gives you a good feeling what academia is about, what certain words mean (and how academics think).